# Can I use the Box API to create a secure online upload only web form?

Tags: box-api

Is it possible to use the Box.com API to allow users of my website to upload files via an online form, without being able to edit or see other files I have currently online? For example, hardcoding user credentials in a script with "upload only" access.

Is this possible? And if so how can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Box has an [upload widget](https://support.box.com/entries/20359393-Upload-Widget) that you can easily embed into your site to accept files.

If you are looking to do this programmatically, then you can use an [SDK](http://developers.box.com/sdks/) or [upload method](http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-upload-a-file) to upload a file from a form. For authentication, you can either ask to authenticate the user with their Box account or use a system level user that belongs to you.